# Changing value of Plain Object properties while iterating through it with jQuery $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plain object that contains a list of stringified selector names like so.

```
{selector1: "#selector1", selector2: "#selector2"}
```

I want to iterate through the object with $.each and replace the strings with the values of those objects, i.e. the final result should look like:

```
{selector1: value of $("#selector1"), selector2: value of $("selector2")}
```

The code I have now is:

```
$.each(args.vars, function(key, value){
    if (value.toString().charAt(0) == "#")
        value = $(value).val();
});
```

Problem is that apparently $.each does not pass by reference, so the values in args.vars stay the same, as "value" is discarded at the end of the loop.  How do I change the value of an object's property as I iterate through it with $.each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple `for` loop:

```
for (var key in vars) {
    if (vars[key][0] == "#") {
        vars[key] = $(vars[key]).val();
    }
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xYZka/

Answer (score 0):

```
args.vars[key] = $(value).val();
```